# Why is Adam optimization unable to converge in linear regression?

Tags: r, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I am studying Adam optimizer. This is a toy problem. In R, I generate some artificial data:

Y = c0 + c1 * x1 + c2 * x2 + noise

In the above equation, x1, x2 and noise are normal random numbers I generated in R, theta = [c0, c1, c2] is the parameter I try to estimate with Adam optimizer. For this simple regression problem, I can use analytical method to determine the theta parameter which is the k in my R codes below.

Regarding Adam algorithm, I use the formulae from this site

[Overview: Adam](https://ruder.io/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#adam)

I change the step size eta in this parametric study. The final theta from Adam algorithm is not the same as the analytical solution *k* in my R codes. 
[image: Norm]
I checked my codes many times. I run the codes line by line and cannot understand why Adam algorithm cannot converge.

Added:
I changed the algorithm to AMSGrad. It perform better than Adam in this case. However, AMSGrad does not converge.
[image: AMSGrad]

```
rm(list = ls())  

n=500
x1=rnorm(n,mean=6,sd=1.6)
x2=rnorm(n,mean=4,sd=2.5)

X=cbind(x1,x2)
A=as.matrix(cbind(intercept=rep(1,n),x1,x2))
Y=-20+51*x1-15*x2+rnorm(n,mean=0,sd=2);


k=solve(t(A)%*%A,t(A)%*%Y) # k is the parameters determined by analytical method
MSE=sum((A%*%k-Y)^2)/(n);

iterations=4000 # total number of steps
epsilon = 0.0001 # set precision
eta=0.04 # step size
beta1=0.9
beta2=0.999

t1=integer(iterations)
t2=matrix(0,iterations,3)
t3=integer(iterations)

epsilon1=1E-8 # small number defined for numerical computation
X=as.matrix(X)# convert data table X into a matrix
N=dim(X)[1] # total number of observations
X=as.matrix(cbind(intercept=rep(1,length(N)),X))# add a column of ones to represent intercept
np=dim(X)[2] # number of parameters to be determined
theta=matrix(rnorm(n=np,mean=0,sd=2),1,np) # Initialize theta:1 x np matrix
m_i=matrix(0,1,np) # initialization, zero vector
v_i=matrix(0,1,np) # initialization, zero vector

for(i in 1:iterations){
  error=theta%*%t(X)-t(Y) # error = (theta * x' -Y'). Error is a 1xN row vector;
  grad=1/N*error%*%X # Gradient grad is 1 x np vector
  m_i=beta1*m_i+(1-beta1)*grad # moving average of gradient, 1 x np vector
  v_i=beta2*v_i+(1-beta2)*grad^2 # moving average of squared gradients, 1 x np vector
  # corrected moving averages
  m_corrected=m_i/(1-beta1^i)
  v_corrected=v_i/(1-beta2^i)
  d_theta=eta/(sqrt(v_corrected)+epsilon1)*m_corrected
  theta=theta-d_theta
  L=sqrt(sum((d_theta)^2)) # calculating the L2 norm
  t1[i]=L # record the L2 norm in each step
  if ((is.infinite(L))||(is.nan(L))) {
    print("Learning rate is too large. Lowering the rate may help.")
    break
  }
  else if (L<=epsilon) {
    print("Algorithm convergence is reached.")
    break # checking whether convergence is obtained or not
  }
  # if (i==1){
  #   browser()
  # }
}

plot(t1,type="l",ylab="norm",lwd=3,col=rgb(0,0,1))
k
theta
```

Comment: If `eta` is large it possible it keeps hopping around the optimum.

Comment: This is also stated in the article you show: "*This way, AMSGrad results in a non-increasing step size, which avoids the **problems suffered by Adam.***".

Comment: AMSGrad will perform much better than Adam. But it may not produce the global minimum. I tried AMSGrad.